# RealmSwift - begin/commit writes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm, cllocation

In my fitness tracker app, I save current run and invoke reverse geolocation method, that is supposed to get the location name where run took place.

First I write 'latestRun' to realm, then I wait for the reverse geocoding to complete and try to modify 'latestRun' variable

```
try! realm.write {
        realm.add(latestRun)
    }

if !savedLocations.isEmpty
    {
         ReverseGeocoder.getPlace(latitude: savedLocations[0].latitude, longitude: savedLocations[0].longitude, completionHandler: {
            place in
            realm.beginWrite()
            try! realm.write {
                latestRun.place = place

            }
            try! realm.commitWrite()

        })
    }
```

it results with an exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'The
>   Realm is already in a write transaction'

What am I doing wrong? What I found in docs is that `beginWrite()` and `commitWrite()` methods should be used in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use neither `commitWrite()` nor `beginWrite()`

```
try! realm.write {
   latestRun.place = place
 }
```

is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the line

```
realm.beginWrite()
```

just before

```
try! realm.write {
```

They both do the same thing, opening a "writing session". You should keep just one.

Note: if you delete the `beginWrite` line and decide to go with the closure variant don't forget to also delete the line

```
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Comment: now i have ` fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Can't commit a non-existing write transaction" `

Comment: That's because you left the line `try! realm.commitWrite()`. You should delete it as well.